# Put row and column titles using grid.arrange in R

Tags: r, visualization

The data for the ggplots:

```
set.seed(0)

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

c <- list()

for (k in 1:9) c[[k]] <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10)),aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line()

grid.arrange (c[[1]],c[[2]],c[[3]],c[[4]],c[[5]]
,c[[6]],c[[7]],c[[8]],c[[9]],ncol=3, nrow=3, widths = c(4,4,4) ,heights = c(4,4,4))
```

I want titles for each row and each column.

The shape of the output would be something like this:

```
          CTitle 1 CTitle 2 CTitle 3
RTitle1   plot1     plot2   plot3
RTitle2   plot4     plot5   plot6
RTitle3   plot7     plot8   plot9
```

Comment: @SRivero Wonderful! It worked prefectly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use nested arrangeGrob calls for each column/row, setting the top and left argument. Something like this:

```
grid.arrange (arrangeGrob(c[[1]], top="CTitle1", left="RTitle1"),arrangeGrob(c[[2]],top="CTitle2"),arrangeGro‌​b(c[[3]],top="CTittl‌​e3"),arrangeGrob(c[[‌​4]], left="RTitle2"),c[[5]],c[[6]],arrangeGrob(c[[7]],left="RTitl‌​e3"),c[[8]],c[[9]],n‌​col=3, nrow=3, widths = c(4,4,4) ,heights = c(4,4,4))
```

Below is a code to streamline the process thanks to @eipi10

```
# Create list of plots
set.seed(0)
pl = lapply(1:9, function(i) {
  p = ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10)),aes(x, y)) + 
              geom_line()
})

# Create row and column titles
col.titles = paste("C_Title", 1:3)
row.titles = paste("R_Title", 4:6)

# Add row titles
pl[1:3] = lapply(1:3, function(i) arrangeGrob(pl[[i]], left=row.titles[i]))

# Add column titles and lay out plots
grid.arrange(grobs=lapply(c(1,4,7), function(i) {
  arrangeGrob(grobs=pl[i:(i+2)], top=col.titles[i/3 + 1], ncol=1)
}), ncol=3)
```

Comment: @S Rivero, How might one change the font size of the row/column labels?

Comment: This results in plots that are slightly different sizes across the columns (the left plots are smaller). How can the row labels be added keeping all plots the same size?

Answer (score 4):

here's another option:

```
pl <- replicate(12, ggplot(), FALSE)

N <- length(pl)
nr <- 4
nc <- 3


combine <- rbind(tableGrob(t(c(letters[1:nc])), theme = ttheme_minimal(), rows = ""), 
                 cbind(tableGrob(LETTERS[1:nr], theme = ttheme_minimal()), 
                       arrangeGrob(grobs = pl),  size = "last"), size = "last")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(combine)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to load the 'grid' package for this solution. Maybe add "library(grid)" to the sample code?